# Should we have a migration route to IT Security?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

A couple of questions have been flagged today as more appropriate on [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). I thought I'd do a check on what had been migrated there by moderators and came up with the following list:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96553/is-steganography-a-safe-method-migrated?noredirect=1

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96547/building-a-security-framework-migrated?noredirect=1

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95544/what-are-the-chances-of-a-database-being-hacked-migrated?noredirect=1

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94306/storing-sensitive-information-securely-migrated?noredirect=1

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56870/compute-the-aes-encryption-key-given-the-plaintext-and-its-ciphertext-migrated?noredirect=1 (deleted)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87337/how-can-you-become-a-competent-web-application-security-expert-without-breaking-t?noredirect=1

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84989/how-secure-are-the-default-asp-net-membership-and-role-providers-for-sql-server?noredirect=1 (deleted)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32980/pci-encryption-key-management-migrated?noredirect=1 (deleted)

Is this enough evidence to enable the migration route on the close dialog?

Are there any other questions that would be a better fit for IT Security?

Comment: Just noticed this question. I think that there would need to be a bigger wall of questions about IT Security to warrant an extra close option. Oh and sorry for the close vote, I was trying to see if this had already been implemented but it just closed without offering migration options

Comment: @TheLQ - Ah. Don't forget there are no migration options from Meta anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another question migrated:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96445/arent-permanantly-logged-in-accounts-inherently-insecure?noredirect=1

Looks like the frequency is increasing.